# Unexpected keyword argument 'ibm_api_key_id' when using ibm-cos-sdk?

Tags: python, object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

I'm getting a Unexpected keyword argument 'ibm_api_key_id' error argument when using ibm-cos-sdk on python 3.6.2.

I've installed the library in a clean virtual enviroment using these steps:

```
virtualenv --python=python3.5 boto-test
source boto-test/bin/activate
pip install ibm-cos-sdk
```

Then, I've tried to run the example [from here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/libraries/python.html#python):

```
import boto3
import json
import requests
import random
from botocore.client import Config
from pprint import pprint

with open('./credentials.json') as data_file:
    credentials = json.load(data_file)

print("Service credential:")
print(json.dumps(credentials, indent=2))
print("")
print("Connecting to COS...")

# Rquest detailed enpoint list
endpoints = requests.get(credentials.get('endpoints')).json()
#import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

# Obtain iam and cos host from the the detailed endpoints
iam_host = (endpoints['identity-endpoints']['iam-token'])
cos_host = (endpoints['service-endpoints']['cross-region']['us']['public']['us-geo'])

api_key = credentials.get('apikey')
service_instance_id = credentials.get('resource_instance_id')

# Constrict auth and cos endpoint
auth_endpoint = "https://" + iam_host + "/oidc/token"
service_endpoint = "https://" + cos_host

print("Creating client...")
# Get bucket list
cos = boto3.client('s3',
                    ibm_api_key_id=api_key,
                    ibm_service_instance_id=service_instance_id,
                    ibm_auth_endpoint=auth_endpoint,
                    config=Config(signature_version='oauth'),
                    endpoint_url=service_endpoint)


# Call S3 to list current buckets
response = cos.list_buckets()

# Get a list of all bucket names from the response
buckets = [bucket['Name'] for bucket in response['Buckets']]

# Print out the bucket list
print("Current Bucket List:")
print(json.dumps(buckets, indent=2))
print("---")
result = [bucket for bucket in buckets if 'cos-bucket-sample-' in bucket]

print("Creating a new bucket and uploading an object...")
if len(result) == 0 :
   bucket_name = 'cos-bucket-sample-' + str(random.randint(100,99999999));
   # Create a bucket
   cos.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
   # Upload a file
   cos.upload_file('./example.py', bucket_name, 'example-object')

   # Call S3 to list current buckets
   response = cos.list_buckets()

   # Get a list of all bucket names from the response
   buckets = [bucket['Name'] for bucket in response['Buckets']]

   # Print out the bucket list
   print("New Bucket List:")
   print(json.dumps(buckets, indent=2))
   print("---")
else :
   bucket_name = result[0];


# Call S3 to list current objects
response = cos.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name)

# Get a list of all object names from the response
objects = [object['Key'] for object in response['Contents']]

# Print out the object list
print("Objects in %s:" % bucket_name)
print(json.dumps(objects, indent=2))
```

But when running, I get the following output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "boto3test.py", line 1, in
>   
>       import boto3   File "/home/giovanni/Downloads/boto-test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto3/**init**.py",
>   line 16, in 
>       from boto3.session import Session   File "/home/giovanni/Downloads/boto-test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto3/session.py",
>   line 27, in 
>       import botocore.session   File "/home/giovanni/Downloads/boto-test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/session.py",
>   line 37, in 
>       import botocore.credentials   File "/home/giovanni/Downloads/boto-test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py",
>   line 27, in 
>       import httplib ImportError: No module named 'httplib'

Where am I doing something wrong? Shoud I install botocore in my virtualenv?

Comment: Are you muddling up the ordering of the arguments and the variable names they're in? `ibm_api_key_id=api_key` looks like it should be `api_key=ibm_api_key` etc... Anyway the key is `lbm_api_key` isn't an argument you can apss to `boto.Client`... so pass it the stuff it is expecting.

Comment: The problem is that this is the ibm cloud storage api that I've installed with pip. Should at least work with their examples. I'm still trying to figure out if I screwed something when installing, but the instructions are very clear and simple to follow.

Comment: Well, first off mentioning that in your question would be important although, it's rather moot. If you've created a new empty virtualenv, then installed `boto3` into it, then try and use that boto3 like the adapted library you mention - you'll get the above...

Comment: Sorry, I've pasted the wrong line of code up there. I'ts **pip install ibm-cos-sdk**

Comment: Right please [edit] your question to reflect that. Are you sure you're activating your virtual environment and what does `boto3.__file__` show you?

Comment: I'm getting a different error now, when I try to import boto3, I get this error: **ImportError: No module named 'httplib'**, which shoudn't happen when installing boto3 from pip3. I'm pretty confused now.

Comment: Yeah that’s very odd. You didn’t mention it but the credential file is in place, right?  Also, you shouldn’t have to install it separately by the forked botocore is “Ibm-cos-sdk-core”

Comment: Yes, the credential file is in place.

Comment: I have found the problem, it's on IBM's own version of botocore, that's using references that have been renamed on python 3. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2):

edit botocore/credentials.py and change import httplib to import http.client as httplib

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem: 
IBM's library [ibm-cos-sdk-python-core](https://github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-python-core), is their own version of the botocore library, however, on **credentials.py** from their repo, there is a reference to a library that's been renamed on Python 3 (httplib -> http.client).

So my fix was to replace line 27 of credentials.py on my local installation directory from:

```
import httplib
```

To:

```
import http.client as httplib
```

There was an open issue on the case (#1), however, I didn't saw because the repos had no connection to each other and I'm still learning how IBM's libraries work.